# What are the best affordable c++ audio libraries?

Tags: c++, audio, mp3

I'm looking for a c++ audio library that can play mp3s and mix audio. I can spend some money on it, but I'm on a somewhat tight budget, so the less the better. It really needs to just run on Windows and Mac OS X although Linux and embedded devices are a big plus. Anyone know of a good library or two?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about it, but maybe Audacity.

Answer (score 12):

From the game development world, you'll find a lot of good libraries. Obviously "mixing" doesn't tell what exactly you want to do but in a lot of games we mix tracks and sound to get some kind of ambiance so I guess it can be useful for you:

UPDATE: fmod now have a free indie license.

- **FMOD** http://www.fmod.org/ : might be expensive even if they have a "casual" (think "indie") license. However, it's certainly the "standard" in the industry because it's uncontestably very powerful.
- **Irrklang** http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/ : have been used and recommended by several indie game developers. It's cheap, even if you buy the most expensive version.
- **Bass** http://www.un4seen.com/ : used in several games so good quality, but more exepensive than Irrklang while cheaper than FMOD.
- **Clam** http://clam-project.org/ : this is more free and flexible that the previous libraries but also might be too flexible for your need.
- **CAudio** https://github.com/wildicv/cAudio : wrapping OpenAL with a C++ interface and adding higher lever constructs, it might not fit your need, depends, but also I'm not sure of the quality of the library; maybe worth a try as it's the most open-source of all.

If you are not pressed by time (or want to help), there is also [**Plaid/Audio**, a promising software audio processing library which is still a work in progress](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=30172.0) but is extracted from the engine used by [SourceSelf](http://soundselfgame.com/) (a game which [use player's sounds -like, your voice- as input](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/soundself/soundself)).

Answer (score 3):

I'd have a really close look at [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). It's excellent. We're using the sox C++ library to do real time transformation of RTP streams. Works well.

Answer (score 3):

[JUCE](https://juce.com/) is an awfully nice portable toolkit for graphics and audio. The main architect created it for real time audio processing, but it's evolved into a wider range of tools.

Answer (score 2):

No firsthand experience, but [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Though it does do ten zillion more things that you don't mention, I can't fail to recommend [Qt with Phonon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/phonon-overview.html) -- I learned about it only earlier today (from another Q&A on SO!) and it's opening new frontiers for me. If you need even a tiny fraction of the incredible power of Qt, that's definitely something worth trying (LGPL, so free and unencumbered as long as you don't modify the library itself).

Comment: I don't think Qt with phonon supports audio mixing.

Comment: "Work in progress", according to the URL I mentioned (I know, I can't wait either;-).

Answer (score 1):

libmad - MPEG Audio Decoder

http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec)? seems like it would be what you are after.  You are able to grab it from the [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) site.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [TempAu](http://code.google.com/p/tempau/)
It is lightweight and simple, crossplatform and plays mp3.

Comment: It seems that the tempau project isn't mature enough yet! Most of the pages are empty.

Comment: Leads to a dead Google Code link, project is dead too