# Cross Platform (C/C++) Audio Library for MP3, AAC, WAV

Tags: c++, c, audio

I'm trying to find a cross platform audio library that will have the following abilities (in order of importance):

- Full Windows, Mac, Linux support
- C / C++ APIs
- Free/cheap but commercially viable
- MP3 Support
- AAC Support
- WMA Support
- FLAC Support
- OGG Support
- ARM Linux support would be nice
- Open Source

I've found several things like OpenAL, libao, Bass, etc. but they all seem to all either have a limitation of OS, codec or both.  For the most part MP3 and AAC support are a must as I'm working on a media player and would like it to support those common formats.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/994161/10396

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at **[GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/)** and **[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)**.

**EDIT**:

Since you are willing to use Qt, you should definitely check [Qt MultimediaKit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/multimedia.html), which is a part of the [Qt Mobility](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/) project. Phonon is fading away because Qt is investing on MultimediaKit to replace it.

[This example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/multimedia-audiooutput.html) shows how to do simple audio playback. [This example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/player.html) shows how to create a multimedia player. [This example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtquick-components-symbian-1.1/qt-components-example-musicplayer.html) shows a more advanced music player, using Qt and QML.

Comment: Fromt he looks of it, the MultimediaKit is for mobile devices only. I'm working on something for the desktop. Is that correct?

Comment: Wrong. I use QtMultimediaKit on several products for Desktops (Windows/Linux/Mac OS X). ;D

Comment: Weird... I could not get the media player example to even compile for desktop. I always have to ask, are these products you mention anything publicly available?

Comment: They are all open source (FFmpeg, GStreamer, Qt, Qt Multimedia Kit), and you can download the sources and compile them in your computer.

Comment: I know you are trying to ask [about the license](http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing/). I've always used the [LGPL version](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qtmobility/lgpl.html) of Qt and Qt Mobility. So no, my products are not open source.

Comment: LOL... sorry if I was confusing. But what I meant was that I was curious what the products that *you* used the media kit in, the actual names of the products you were working on, not the licensing or anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have anything to show, they are all private projects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are planning on using a framework like Qt.
This has a library called "Phonon" bundled, which is also really nice.
It is built on the corresponding native media framework, so QuickTime on Mac, Windows Media Player on Windows and GTK+ on Linux.

PulseAudio also looks promising without any framework.

Comment: Qt actually was my first choice... I'll look into it.

Comment: I already made a few applications using the Phonon framework. For all the basic stuff it is absolutely great and it automatically supports all codecs QuickTime/WMP/GTK+ supports.

Comment: Anything that I would know? Would love to see some examples.

Comment: No, sorry. Have all been inhouse projects for my company. The most recent one was a listening test software. Hit me up if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [JUCE](http://www.juce.com/). It is like Qt in some respects, but much more audio-centric.I've been using it for some years now and it is well maintained and written.