# How can I use QtMultimediaKit on Desktop?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-mobility

Possibly duplicate question, but I'm not found the answer yet.

So, I'm trying to compile Qt example, called "player". This example uses QtMobility API, but on my PC it doesn't compiles. In particular, compiler shows me
`fatal error: qmediaplayer.h: No such file or directory` on Desktop target. But when setting Symbian target, it compiles successfully.

Also, considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182074/cross-platform-c-c-audio-library-for-mp3-aac-wav#comment13261880_9182295) post, I suppose this is possible, and I'm doing something wrong.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to install QtMobility packet inside your QtSDK. If you use system Qt in Ubuntu, install `qtmobility-dev` packet.

Comment: I've already install QtMobility via Qt package manager. As i said, example "player" compiles in Symbian-mode, but doesn't compiles on Desktop.

Comment: There is no QtMobility in Qt package for Desktop Qt. You need to install them manually.

Comment: So if you mind, answer your own question and accept. Add tag on which system. Even if reputation points is not your aim, it may be helpfull for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed `qtmobility` packet on my Ubuntu. The problem was that the Mobility API is missing in Qt package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Installing QtMobility on desktop at the moment is not great idea (it is available only on Linux OS if I am not wrong).

Better wait for QT5. From what I have read so far, QtMobility will be merged with core components and made available to desktops too.

I know its bit older question, but just want to keep up to date if someone else is searching for solution.

---

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15536