# Play Music File in C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, audio, playback

I'm working on creating my own alarm, and I would like to play my own music files using c/c++. The only C++ function I could find that plays anything is PlaySound(), but I can't seem to get that to work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have included `Winmm.lib`, which lets me play the default sound, but now i'm trying to play my music file. (in wma format).

This is my code so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main(){
  PlaySound(TEXT("test.wma"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
  return 0;
}
```

I've also added the `SND_NODEFAULT` flag in there as well so I could stop hearing the default sound.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to get that to work"? What happens? Does it make any sound at all? Does the function return an error (which you don't check here)? Also just throwing it out there, but there are easily [other C++ functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161(v=vs.85).aspx) that can play media files.

Comment: It could be that test.wma is not in your program's current directory and thus the PlaySound() function can't find it.  As a test, try supplying the full path to the file, e.g. something like  PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Vince\\MySoundsFolder\\test.wma"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);

Comment: Consider the [Stk](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/index.html) sound library for C++

Comment: int ret = GetLastError(); write line after playsound() statement. And check The value of ret.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `PlaySound` supports only `.wav` files.

If you want to play `.wma` you need either to use [Audio Compression Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or one of the  [third party audio libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749414/2786682).

Answer (score 1):

Try with simple c++ code in VC++.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::cout<<"Sound playing... enjoy....!!!";
PlaySound("C:\\temp\\sound_test.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME); //SND_FILENAME or SND_LOOP

return 0;
}
```